# Can not connect to dl-ssl.google.com

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ping, icmp

I want to update Android SDK and Android Platform-tools in my Ubuntu. Ubuntu is a guest system in VirtualBox and the host system is Windows-64bit.
The strang thing is, when I update Android SDK in Android SDK Manager, it can not connect to http://dl-ssl.google.com. 
I try to ping dl-ssl.google.com in my Ubuntu, it happens nothing and times out. In Ubuntu I can ping other website like Yahoo normally. But, when I ping the address in the host system, it works normally and gets ICMP_REPLY package.
Why can't I ping the same adress in my Ubuntu and Windows?